# Angular 2 how to prevent subscribe from firing unless the either of the two values returned by map has changed

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, angular2-observables

I've got a simple issue that's not so easy to resolve I've found out, I'm trying to make a subscribe not fire unless either of the two values `sorting.changes` and `pagination.changes` have changed. I'm guessing `distinctUntilChanged` should be used, however I cannot figure out what to provide as its arguments since I've got two values that needs to be checked instead of one.

**EDIT (the correct subscribe call this time):** Here's the subscribe call:

```
this.requestParamsSubscription = this.store.select('brands')
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .map((brands: IBrandsStorage) => {
    return {sorting: brands.sorting, pagination: brands.pagination};
  })
  .subscribe(
    params => {
      this.store.dispatch({type: BrandsActions.GET_BRANDS_REQUEST});
    }
  );
```

`changes` of the objects is a simple numeric counter which keeps track of changes, I figured I could use this to check whether the objects have changed since the last time.

Got any ideas?

Comment: The change to the title is not consistent with the question text: "unless the two values all and total have changed". I don't mind changing the answer, but the question should be changed, too: "unless *either of* the values all *or* total have changed".

Comment: Edited to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`distinctUntilChanged`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinctUntilChanged) can be passed a comparison function (which should return `true` if the arguments are unchanged). If either `all` or `total` have to have changed, you can use:

```
this.brandsStorageSubscription = this.store.select('brands')
  .map((brands: IBrandsStorage) => ({ all: brands.all, total: brands.total }))
  .distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => (a.all === b.all) && (a.total === b.total))
  .subscribe(
    brands => {
      console.log(brands);
      this.total = brands.total;
      this.brands = brands.all;
    }
  );
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't appear to run. I accidently posted the wrong subscribe call, but in my other one `all` and `total` are both objects containing some properties and also another object as one of these properties. Does it still work to compare them with `===` for deep objects?

Comment: No. You will have to provide an implementation that returns `true` if you consider there to be no change. It's up to you.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Sorry I updated question with the correct code and the correct description. Take a look. I added a `changes` property to both objects which is just a counter that keeps track of number of changes. I figured I can use this as the comparitor.

Comment: Check the answer, as the logic has changed due to your changing the question. Also, it's not a good idea to add the solution to the question; it's more confusing and less likely to be useful to others. This question now makes less sense.

Comment: Ye sorry I realised you edited the answer. Also updated question to make it correct again.

Comment: Thanks. That's great. It'll make more sense to others reading it, now.